# How to print numbers from 1 to 10 using a loop in Brainfuck? Is it even possible?

Tags: loops, brainfuck, esoteric-languages

How to print numbers from 1 to 10 using a loop in Brainfuck? Is it even possible?
I am looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: I have been searching for so long and haven't found any example of using the loop in Brainfack in such way

Comment: Brainf**k is Turing complete, so yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  Cell 0 to '1'
>++++++++++  cell 1 to '\n'
>+++++++++  cell 2 to 9 as counter
[  Print numbers 1 to 9
<<  Data pointer to cell 0
.+  Print and increment cell 0
>.  Data pointer to cell 1 and print the newline
>-  Data pointer to cell 2 and decrement counter
]  Loop till counter is 0
+++++++++  Set cell 2 to 9
[  Set cell 0 to '1'
<<-  Data pointer to cell 0 and decrement
>>-  Data pointer to cell 2 and decrement counter
]  Loop till counter is 0
<<.  Data pointer to cell 0 and print '1'
-.   Decrement cell 0 and print '0'
>.   Data pointer to cell 1 and print newline
```

#### Readable version:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>
++++++++++>
+++++++++[<<.+>.>-]
+++++++++[<<->>-]
<<.-.>.
```

#### Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

#### Live demo:

[Brainf**k print 1 to 10](http://tpcg.io/RotMkD)
[Brainf**k Visualizer](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKz4KKysrKysrKysrKz4rKysrKysrKytbPDwuKz4uPi1dKysrKysrKysrWzw8LT4+LV08PC4tLj4uCg==)

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

```
-[>+<-----]>---<++++++++++<++++++++++[>>.+<.<-]>>---------.-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pO20YXBGLtgISNNhwgMaPt7PS0bfRsgGrsdGFAT1fv/38A)

**END TL;DR**

In order to program in BrainF**k, pretend like every program (even simple ones) will need to start out with a layout.

The pseudo-code for this would be something like:

```
Generate the character '0'
Move left and generate '\n'
Move left and generate the counter (10 numbers in this case)
Loop: Get back to the character '0', print it, increment it to '1', go to the newline, print it, go to the counter, and decrement it. End it when the counter is 0
Generate '1' and print it
Generate '0' and print it
```

However, the last two steps could be simplified to just:

```
Go back to the digit '9'
Decrement it until '1' and print
Decrement it until '0' and print
```

This saves a lot of time and <s>bytes</s> characters.

To generate the character '0', you generate the integer 48 (because that's it's ASCII value). To do this you can go to [Esolangs' BF Constants](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants). Looking up the number 48, we find `-[>+<-----]>---`

Our program so far is `-[>+<-----]>---` to generate `0`

Next, move left and generate `\n` (newline). We can use `<++++++++++`. Notice how it is completely plus signs. This is because there is not much room to reduce the character count at the number 10.

Our program so far is `-[>+<-----]>---<++++++++++`

Then, move left and generate the counter. We want the counter to be 10 to print numbers from 0 to 9. `<++++++++++`.

Our program so far is `-[>+<-----]>---<++++++++++<++++++++++`

After that, start the loop `[`. Go to the '0' `>>`, print it `.`, increment it `+`, go to the newline and print `<.`, Go to the counter and decrement it, and end the loop when it is zero `<-]`. `[>>.+<.<-]`

Our program so far is `-[>+<-----]>---<++++++++++<++++++++++[>>.+<.<-]`

Finally, go to the '9' `>>`, decrement it until it is 1 and print `---------.`, and decrement it until it is 0 and print `-.`. `---------.-.`

The program is finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Let address 0 be the digit we want to print, starting with '0'
>++++++++++ Let address 1 be our newline character
>+++++++++ Let address 2 be our counter, starting at 9 
[
  - Decrement the counter
  <<+. Increment the digit we want to print and print it
  >. Print the newline
  > Make sure we're at the counter again before we loop back
]

<< Move back to address 0
--------. Make address 0 '1'
-. Make address 0 '0'
```

[Live demo](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=KysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrKysrIExldCBhZGRyZXNzIDAgYmUgdGhlIGRpZ2l0IHdlIHdhbnQgdG8gcHJpbnQsIG1ha2UgaXQgJzAnCj4rKysrKysrKysrIExldCBhZGRyZXNzIDEgYmUgb3VyIG5ld2xpbmUgY2hhcmFjdGVyCj4rKysrKysrKysgTGV0IGFkZHJlc3MgMiBiZSBvdXIgY291bnRlciwgc3RhcnRpbmcgYXQgOSAKWwogIC0gRGVjcmVtZW50IHRoZSBjb3VudGVyCiAgPDwrLiBJbmNyZW1lbnQgdGhlIGRpZ2l0IHdlIHdhbnQgdG8gcHJpbnQgYW5kIHByaW50IGl0CiAgPi4gUHJpbnQgdGhlIG5ld2xpbmUKICA-IE1ha2Ugc3VyZSB3ZSdyZSBhdCB0aGUgY291bnRlciBhZ2FpbiBiZWZvcmUgd2UgbG9vcCBiYWNrCl0KCjw8IE1vdmUgYmFjayB0byBhZGRyZXNzIDAKLS0tLS0tLS0uIE1ha2UgYWRkcmVzcyAwICcxJwotLiBNYWtlIGFkZHJlc3MgMCAnMCc$)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Here's the code: `++++++++++>++++++++++[>+++++<-]>-.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>+.<<.>>--------.-.` It could be shorter, however, it still accomplishes the same task. Brainf*** can theoretically perform any computation, as it is Turing complete. This is just one of those computations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
+++++++++>>++++++++[-<++++++>][-]>++++[-<++++++++>]<<<[->+.>.<<]>[-]+++++++[-<+++++++>]<.-.
```

It outputs `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`.

We have this (each line is after the next cell-affecting instruction, which are `+ - .`):

```
| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | Output                |
+----+----+----+----+-----------------------+
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                       |
|  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                       |
|  2 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                       |
...
|  8 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                       |
|  9 |  0 |  0 |  0 |                       |
...                                           (first loop)
|  9 | 48 |  0 |  0 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  0 |  1 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  0 |  2 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  0 |  3 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  0 |  4 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  0 |  3 |                       | (enter second loop)
|  9 | 48 |  1 |  3 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  2 |  3 |                       |
...
|  9 | 48 |  8 |  3 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  8 |  2 |                       |
|  9 | 48 |  9 |  2 |                       |
...
|  9 | 48 | 16 |  2 |                       |
|  9 | 48 | 16 |  1 |                       |
|  9 | 48 | 17 |  1 |                       |
...
|  9 | 48 | 24 |  1 |                       |
|  9 | 48 | 24 |  0 |                       |
|  9 | 48 | 25 |  0 |                       |
...
|  0 | 48 | 32 |  0 |                       | (exit second loop)
|  8 | 48 | 32 |  0 |                       | (enter third loop)
|  8 | 49 | 32 |  0 |                       |
|  8 | 49 | 32 |  0 | 1                     |
|  8 | 49 | 32 |  0 | 1_                    | (underscores are spaces)
|  7 | 49 | 32 |  0 | 1_                    |
|  7 | 50 | 32 |  0 | 1_                    |
|  7 | 50 | 32 |  0 | 1_2                   |
|  7 | 50 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_                  |
|  6 | 50 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_                  |
|  6 | 51 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_                  |
|  6 | 51 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3                 |
|  6 | 51 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_                |
|  5 | 51 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_                |
|  5 | 52 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_                |
|  5 | 52 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4               |
|  5 | 52 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_              |
|  4 | 52 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_              |
|  4 | 53 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_              |
|  4 | 53 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5             |
|  4 | 53 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_            |
|  3 | 53 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_            |
|  3 | 54 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_            |
|  3 | 54 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6           |
|  3 | 54 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_          |
|  2 | 54 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_          |
|  2 | 55 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_          |
|  2 | 55 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7         |
|  2 | 55 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_        |
|  1 | 55 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_        |
|  1 | 56 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_        |
|  1 | 56 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8       |
|  1 | 56 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_      |
|  0 | 56 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_      |
|  0 | 57 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_      |
|  0 | 57 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9     |
|  0 | 57 | 32 |  0 | 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_    | (exit third loop)
+----+----+----+----+-----------------------+
Then cell C2 is set to 0 and used to set cell C1 to 49 (charater 1).
It prints C1, then removes one and prints it again, giving an output of:
1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10 (underscores are spaces)
```

It's for me the simplest program to print the integers from 1 to 10.

If you want each number to be on its own line, replace the `>>>++++[-<++++++++>]<<<` by `++++++++++`.

Issue [SOLVED]: instead of printing `10` at the end, it prints `:`...